# Ebay API item listing link to ebay site lost when on a mobile device

Tags: android, mobile

I have been trying to workout why a previously correct link that worked on a mobile device is no longer working. It works fine when you look at it on PC or Mac, but on a mobile device it redirects to their mobile site and the reference to the item is lost. For example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Transformers-Armada-Supercon-Optimus-Prime-/161418494602?pt=UK_ToysGames_ActionFigures_ActionFigures_JN">Transformers Armada "Supercon" Optimus Prime </a>
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?